# Json parse array with multiple string

Tags: android, json, parsing

i have this input:

```
[
"1",
"2",
"3",
"5",
"6",
"9",
"10"
]
```

Could anyone tell me how to parse this kind of json file, that I get from the web? It doesn't have any key for the attribute or something like that.

Comment: did you check this out: http://www.json.org/ . It's an array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);  // get the response as JSONArray

for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++)
{                   
    Log.v("ALL--", array.getString(i));   // get the values as string using for loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With org.json package, like this (assuming it is in a string):

```
JSONArray myJSONArray = new JSONArray(inputString);
```

You can then get the individual elements using:

```
myJSONArray.getString(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are having **JSONArray as your response string** so you need to **create JSONArray** for that

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString);
```

Now, you can **retrieve the values by their index positions**.like,

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
   String value = jsonArray.getString(i);
}
```

Complete code to parse this JSON is,

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString);
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
   String value = jsonArray.getString(i);
}
```